# How to display text over AppBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to display text message above app bar like this,

[image]

How can I achieve this with flutter?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There is no problem if you use a Column, but the question is... what happen when you do scroll? "Connecting" label disappear and appbar keep visible?

Comment: @Maikzen appbar keep visible when scrolling.

Comment: And connecting label too?

Comment: Yes connecting label also visible when scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(customSize),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Connecting...'),
              AppBar(
                title: Text('Recents'),
              )
            ],
          )),
      body: content...,
    );
```

You can add as parent `SafeArea` to avoid intrusions by the operating system

Comment: I run your code. I got this result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkTN6Yp1FKrYj6gaywYAq8FpzBBDrTgv/view?usp=sharing

Connecting... message shows above status bar. I want Connecting... just before AppBar.

Comment: Just put `SafeArea` as parent of Scaffold like i said :D

Answer (score 2):

You can also use padding for alignment.

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _showConnecting = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // 24 for default icon size
        toolbarHeight: _showConnecting ? kToolbarHeight + 24 : kToolbarHeight,
        centerTitle: false,
        leadingWidth: 0,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            if (_showConnecting)
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.network_cell_sharp),
                    Text("Connecting.."),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            Container(
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              alignment: Alignment(-.8, 0),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Text("Recent Mentions"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
              44,
              (index) => Container(
                height: 100,
                color: index.isEven ? Colors.amber : Colors.cyanAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _showConnecting = !_showConnecting;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }}
```

[image]

Comment: Result as per your code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CTfPiK-otg3yXoj0lcfaUMPkEj1l3IBr/view?usp=sharing

How to give full width message in drawer and action as well?

Comment: instead of using `leading` and `actions` use second `Container(child:Row(<leading, title,Actions >))` to place them

Comment: Thank You @Yeasin Sheikh

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold -> Body -> Column -> [ ...widgets, AppBar() ]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same design, Consider using this to achieve a consistency of colors between the appBar and statusBar:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.black, // status bar color
  ));
}
```

On the other hand, appBar title property is a widget, you can modify it as you wish !

Comment: Thanks for answer. First I want to display message above appbar.